# Get It Now button missing from app

Tags: appexchange

I created a package and listed on appexchange in private listing. But it does not show "Get it now" button. What can be wrong?

Comment: Is it a paid application? If so, has it been through security review?

Comment: it is not paid app.

Comment: just realised, it was still showing paid app, I changed to free but still the button not appearing.

Comment: I think you'll still need to submit the uploaded package for security review. In the publishing console you can see the list of packages that you've uploaded, there should be a start review link next to that. Security review is free for free apps

Comment: It asks to register at Salesforce.com Partner Portal, i did so but no response yet. It looks it is time consuming process.

Comment: Yeah, it's recently taken us the best part of 10 weeks to get an app through!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app has not yet passed security review it will need to do so before other organisations can install it. Security reviews for free apps do not cost anything, but the code still needs to be checked to ensure that the app poses no risks to the security of the client's org and data.